Material UI Elements not Aligning/Filling area in React/Typescript based front end code
Material UI Elements not Aligning/Filling area and I have tried everything, setting heights, centering, nothing is working. This is for a frontend component, and I have been fighting it for the entire week trying to get it to align and nothing is working. I added some more text here so I can actually make the post on here.
enter image description here
return (
        <Box sx={{height: '85.33px', width: '100%'}}>
            <header
                style={{
                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '85.34px',
                    display: 'flex',
                    padding: '24px',
                    zIndex: 100,
                    position: 'relative',
                    gridArea: 'pageHeader',
                    boxShadow: '0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                    backgroundImage: 'none, linear-gradient(90deg, #60287E, #4674BC)',
                    backgroundPosition: 'center',
                }}>
            <h1
                style={{
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    fontSize: '32px',
                    wordBreak: 'break-word',
                    marginBottom: '0px',
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontWeight: 700,
                    lineHeight: '0',
                    display: 'block',
                    marginBlockStart: '0.67em',
                    marginBlockEnd: '0.67em',
                    marginInlineStart: '0px',
                    marginInlineEnd: '0px',
                    unicodeBidi: 'isolate',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                >Entra User Search</h1>
            </header>            
            <Box sx={{width: "100%", paddingTop: '24px', paddingBottom: '24px', paddingLeft: '24px', paddingRight: '24px', }}>
                <Box sx={{width: "100%", alignItems: "center"}}>
                    <Stack direction="row" spacing = {2} alignItems="center" justifyContent='flex-start'> 
                        <TextField
                            label="Email Address"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                            variant="outlined"
                            size='medium'
                            sx={{ width: '30ch', height: '36.5px', boxSizing: "border-box", display: "inline-grid"}}
                            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                            error={!isValidEmail(email) && email.length > 0}
                            helperText={!isValidEmail(email) && email.length > 0 ? 'Invalid email address': ''}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            label="Select a Subscription"
                            value={selectedOption}
                            onChange={(e) => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)}
                            variant="outlined"
                            size='medium'
                            select
                            sx={{ width: '30ch', height: '36.5px', boxSizing: "border-box", display: "inline-grid"}}
                            SelectProps={{
                                MenuProps: {
                                    PaperProps: {style: {maxHeight: 48 * 4.5 + 8, width: 'auto',},},
                                },
                            }}>
                            {options?.map(option => (
                                <MenuItem
                                    key={option.displayName}   
                                    value={option.displayName + option.id} 
                                    style={{ display: 'flex' , justifyContent: 'flex-start'}} 
                                >
                                    {option.displayName}
                                </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </TextField>
                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={fetchData} sx={{height:'36.5px'}}>
                            Search
                        </Button>
                    </Stack> 
                </Box>
                <Divider style={{ marginTop: '20px', marginBottom: '20px' }} />
                <Tabs
                    value={tabIndex}
                    onChange={(_event, newIndex) => setTabIndex(newIndex)}
                    sx={{
                        '.MuiTab-root': {
                            fontSize: '1rem',
                            borderRadius: '10px',
                            border: '1px solid primary.main',
                            backgroundColor: 'white', 
                            padding: '20px 20px 20px',
                        },
                        '.MuiTabs-indicator': {
                            backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
                        },
                        '.MuiTab-root.Mui-selected': {
                            backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',
                            color: 'black',
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    <Tab label="Applications" />
                    <Tab label="Groups" />
                    <Tab label="Azure Role Assignments" />
                </Tabs>
                {tabIndex === 0 && (
                    <div>
                        {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                        {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
                        {!loading && !error && aData && aData.map.length === 0 && ( <div>No data available</div> )}
                        {!loading && !error && aData && aData.map.length > 0 && (
                            <BackstageTable
                                columns={appColumns}
                                data={aData}
                                title="Applications"
                                options={tableOptions}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                )}
                {tabIndex === 1 && (
                    <div>
                        {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                        {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
                        {!loading && !error && gData && gData.map.length === 0 && (
                            <div>No data available</div>
                        )}
                        {!loading && !error && gData && gData.map.length > 0 && (
                            <BackstageTable
                                columns={groupColumns}
                                data={gData}
                                title="Groups"
                                options={tableOptions}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                )}
                {tabIndex === 2 && (
                    <div>
                        {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                        {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
                        {!loading && !error && azRoleData && azRoleData.map.length === 0 && (
                            <div>No data available</div>
                        )}
                        {!loading && !error && azRoleData && azRoleData.map.length > 0 && (
                            <BackstageTable
                                columns={AZRoleColumns}
                                data={azRoleData}
                                title="Azure Role Assignments"
                                options={tableOptions}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                )}
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );

